# Tesseract: UnsatisfiedLinkError - undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I'm getting the following error when I tired to run [Tess4j sample program](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPICreate': /usr/local/lib/libtesseract.so: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPICreate
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:350)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:330)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
    at $Proxy0.TessBaseAPICreate(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:253)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:220)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:166)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:151)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm using Redhat Linux 32 bit.

Comment: Have you downloaded the [source](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout), [build](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling) and install Tesseract 3.02? Once you got libtesseract.so built, then you can proceed with the Java part.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like binding error - shared lbrarz was found, but contents difer from what java expected.  You will have to check versions carefully.